# Como gerar um schema XML, onde tenho alguns nós com namespace e outros sem

Tags: xml, xmldocument, xml-namespaces, xml-schema

Estou tentando gerar um schema XML, para futuras validações, onde alguns atributos contém um namespace específico, e outros não:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
   <title>Titulo do XML</title>
   <description> Descricao do XML </description>
   <link>http://www.linkDoXml.com.br</link>
   <item>
      <g:id>11111111111</g:id>
      <title> Titulo do item </title>
      <description> Descricao do item </description>
      <g:category> Categoria 2 </g:category>
      <g:product_type>tipo 1</g:product_type>
   </item>
   <item>
      <g:id>2222222222</g:id>
      <title> Titulo do item 2</title>
      <description> Descricao do item 2</description>
      <g:category> Categoria 2 </g:category>
      <g:product_type>tipo 1</g:product_type>
   </item>
</root>
```

Nesse exemplo, tenho os atributos "id", "category" e "product_type" com o namespace "g", que é o namespace do Google Shopping (http://base.google.com/ns/1.0), e o restante dos atributos sem namespace.

Como seria o schema desse xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu esquema será dividido em dois documentos: um armazenando as informações do namespace default (""), e o outro no namespace do google (`http://base.google.com/ns/1.0`). Para gerar o esquema (em dois arquivos), você pode usar o utilitário `xsd.exe` (vem instalado com o SDK do Windows, ou no Visual Studio). Se você armazenar o conteúdo do XML acima num arquivo chamado `root.xml`, e executar o comando abaixo:

```
xsd.exe root.xml
```

Então os arquivos seguintes serão gerados:

**root.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:app1="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <xs:import namespace="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" schemaLocation="root_app1.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
        <xs:element name="link" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
        <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="app1:id" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element ref="app1:category" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element ref="app1:product_type" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="root" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**root.app1.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:mstns="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:app1="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <xs:element name="id" msdata:Prefix="g" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="category" msdata:Prefix="g" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="product_type" msdata:Prefix="g" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```